# Is the closure of a closable projection continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach Space and let $P$ be a densely defined operator on $X$
such that

$P$ is closable

$R(P)\subset D\left( P\right) $ and $P^{2}=P$

Is $\overline{P}$ an everywhere defined continuous projection ?

Thank you